# awk: illegal primary in regular expression vault-(?!etcd|operator)

Tags: awk, regular-expression

Need to improve a regex for awk. It works on regex101.

`/vault-(?!etcd|operator)/`

Should only match:

```
vault-etcd-abc123
vault-operator-def456
vault-ghi789 <--
```

Tried:

```
awk '/vault-(?!etcd|operator)/ {print $1;exit}'

awk: illegal primary in regular expression vault-(?!etcd|operator) at !etcd|operator)
```

I have tried escaping some of the special characters such as `|`, but then it does not give the expected results.

Comment: Awk understands extended regular expressions, not PCREs. That site is a poor site to use for testing regular expressions as it doesn't even support POSIX basic or extended expressions, as far as I can see.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y

Comment: rexv should be a better site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(?!...)` is a `perl` regular expression operator while `awk` regexps are a variant of the POSIX extended regular expressions (ERE).

`(?!...)` is not incompatible with EREs as `(?` is unspecified in EREs, so `awk` implementations could choose to implement that operator as it wouldn't affect portable applications which cannot use it.

But while there are some `egrep`/`grep -E` implementations like ast-open's that do support it, I don't know of any `awk` implementations that does (based on the error message, yours seems to be based on Brian Kernighan's original implementation which may not even support the `{x,y}` interval operators). awk cannot use PCRE (a portable perl-compatible regexp libraries) as perl regexps as a whole are incompatible with `awk` REs (like for the alternation operator behaviour, or `\b` which means something different in `perl` and `awk`).

Here, you could use `perl` instead:

```
perl -lae 'print $F[0] if /vault-(?!etcd|operator)/'
```

Or you could use a `grep` with `-o` and PCRE support, like `pcregrep` or GNU `grep` with it's `-P` option:

```
grep -Po '^\s*+\K(?=.*vault-(?!etcd|operator))\S+'
```